Why I am seeing peaking at NMOS switch output?
I am designing a simple switch using an NMOS. The NMOS P/N is PMV65UNE. The circuit is given below.

I am observing a peaking at the output of the MOSFET. Please see the below image.

Below is the enhanced image.

May I know why it is happening?

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/525167/miller-capacitance-in-mosfet/525214#525214

It looks like capacitive coupling between gate and drain. So, when the gate-source is rising up to 3.3 volts (in order to activate the MOSFET), before that activation fully happens (or during that activation process) the 43 pF \$C_{rss}\$ couples the rising gate signal to the drain and you get a little transient. Once the channel starts to turn on this overshoot rapidly disappears.
I mean that the drain resistor is 1 MΩ and that makes it susceptible to these sorts of overshoots from the gate via \$C_{rss}\$. You can make the overshoot smaller if your gate signal is ramped up more slowly. However, that may be undesirable for other reasons.
