Calculation of NPN Transistor values
EXPLANATION

Picture 1 is the circuit diagram. I really need an expert suggestion
about this question because I am confused about the Q17.
Q16 is taking the signal from SPWM so the ton is changing and very
short.
When Q16 stops conducting, Q17 will conduct.
I calculated the parameters of Q16 such as Vce should be low so the Ve-Q18 will be low in order to keep the M5 close when its time comes.

Lets come to the Q17 as follow :

when I check the simulation, the Ib-Q17 is 9mA and Ic-Q17 = 0.7A. See Picture 2

Hovewer with Ib=9mA, that means voltage drop across R14 is Vdrop= 9mA
x 1k = 9 V but it isn't in the simulation. You can see the voltage
over R14 (Given as V(a,b)). When Q16 ( Given as V(c) ) stops
conducting, you can see that the voltage drop over R14 is close to 0
but not exactly zero. See Picture 3

Someone told me that '' the base current is flowing for a very short
period of time so R14 will be seen at the emitter side as a beta time
smaller resistor R = R14/beta ''. Based on this suggestion and β=78,
this makes R14/β = 1k/78 = 12.82 ohm.

With Ib=9mA this will cause a 12.82 ohm x 9mA = 0.115 V drop on the
R14. Consequently the Vb of Q17 will be 12V - 0.115V = 11.885V. This
calculation makes the simulation correct.

So, Ib-Q17 = (12V-11.885V)/ 12.82 ohm = 0.0089 A, which makes the
simulation again correct.

Considering 0.6 V Vbe,  the Ve= 11.885V - 0.6V = 11.285V.


QUESTIONS

Is above calculation correct ?

Second question: as you can see in the above calculation, the Ve-Q17
is 11.285V and it has 12V coming from power supply, that means when
Q17 conducts the Vce-Q17 is 12V-11,285 = 0.715V. Does that mean Q17
is used in saturation mode ?

If Q17 is in saturation mode, let say we didn't know our Ic-Q17
but we want to calculate. I said the β=78 in the above calculation because from the simulation results Ic/Ib = 0.7A/9mA = 78.  How would you calculate the Ic-Q17 ? Because I
provided the Vce-sat - Ic from the it's datasheet in Picture 4. There is no 70<β<80 line in the graph.


Picture 1. Circuit Diagram

Source : Me
Picture 2. 9mA of Ib-Q17

Source : Me
Picture 3. V(a,b) and V(c) Waveform

Source : Me
Picture 4. Vce-sat - Ic Graph from the Datasheet

Source: https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/bipolar/2sc2411k.pdf

Source: https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/bipolar/2sc2411k.pdf

This is a repost of your previously deleted question, which is not allowed. Instead of asking a new question, please edit your original question.

Note that Ic/Ib is not "beta". It is Hfe DC, not hfe=beta.

If you noticed, I deleted the poorly explained previous question and post a detailed version so it is not a  reposting the same thing @Hearth

@Mhan - Hi, Re: Similarity to the question from yesterday. Today's question is not a prohibited "delete & repost" because, as you said, it's an expanded version & yesterday's post was not closed. So this question is not evading a previous question being closed. But... Posting (especially deleting & posting) multiple related questions on one topic, can appear to be wasting people's time. They may have invested effort into analysing question X, which then gets deleted and similar question Y is posted on the same topic. Please try to avoid this. Edit (unanswered) questions, when sensible. TY

No, wrong, What is the point of calculating the Q17 base current? If Q17 drives the capacitance load. All we can say is that the Q17 base current will not be larger than (12V - 0.7V)/1k = 11mA  Also, Q17 is not saturated.  To saturate Q17 the base voltage needs to be higher than Vcc.  Why did you choose R12 to be 308.33? Where are you going to buy such a resistance?  R12 should be around (Vin - Vbe)/(0.1*Ic_mx) = (1V - 0.7V)/1mA = 300R, So we can use 300 or 330.

Thank you sir, I understand your point. 1) so what is your opinion about the voltage drop across R14 when Q17 conducts? 2) Sir one thing that I wonder, Ic-Q17 is 0.7A, how would you predict this values ? maybe this question weird to ask but I am just trying to learn my missing information  @G36

As for the collector current, it will be beta times Ib current. The MOSFET switching process is quite complicated. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/525167/miller-capacitance-in-mosfet/525214#525214 Also I do not like that you decided to use M6 and M5. Simply just use Q17, and Q18 to drive the MOSFET directly without M5 and M6.

Sir I dont have any issue with miller plateu voltage or parasitic capacitances. I understand that our load for Q17 is capacitive load. That is okay. If the only thing we know is the Ib will not be larger than (12V - 0.7V)/1k = 11mA and assume that I didnt know my Ic , could you show me how would you determine the beta on ''DC current gain vs Collector current'' graph provided in the question ? @G36

From the graph we see the typical beta will be approximately 220. But we have to include a spread of beta values, -50%, +100. So we can have a beta as low as 110 for this typical BJT.  This is why the vendor ranks the beta spread (letters P, Q , R). Also as we see from the graph the bate will start to drop if Ic > 100mA. So is it very hard to predict the exact value of a beta.
